# Is it safe to build and untrusted Sphinx document?

Tags: source-code, trust

We would like to build a kind of wiki engine and Sphinx seems like the perfect tool for our project, given a complicated list of requirements we have.

So the question is how safe it would be to run `sphinx-build` then `make` (both `LaTeX` and `html`) on an untrusted directory provided by an unknown user.

Note that this will not be Phython documentation project, so there will be no need to run python scripts or activate features such as `doctest` or `autodoc`. However, support for math is vital.

Two followup questions:

1. In case it is not safe, what are the threats and is there a simple way to mitigate the risks?
2. In case it is safe, what about including extensions? We are specially interested in the [tikz](https://bitbucket.org/philexander/tikz) extension. In the tikz's extenstion documentation, they claim that tikz can be used in [readthedocs](http://readthedocs.org/).